# Find word which was the match

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

I have this code where I search a string for words from an array:

```
string wordlist = synonymslistbox.Items[q_index].ToString().Split(':')[0].Replace(',', ' ');

var pattern = new Regex(@"\W");

var qa = pattern.Split(first_sentence).Any(w => wordlist.Contains(w));
```

Now I would like to achieve two things which I cannot figure out how to do.

1. Find out which word was a match. This code just returns `true` if found.
2. When first_sentences is `i like my banjo`  then it should NOT find the letter `a` in `banjo` as the word `a`. It should only read `a` as a single word when it is in a sentence like this: `i like a big beer at the end of the afternoon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. find out witch word was a match. this one just returns true if found.

Instead of any, use where:

```
var qa = pattern.Split(first_sentence).Where(w => wordlist.Contains(w));
```

> 2. when first_sentences is "i like my banjo" then it should NOT find a in banjo as the word a. it should only read a as a single word when
>      it is in a sentence like this below "i like a big beer at the end of
>      the afternoon"

Your wordlist should not be a string but a list or array of strings. Make sure it's a list that has "a" in it. Aside from that your code will work

Comment: it finds the word now but if two words it only return the first halt of the word.
if i my wordlist have "new car" then it only return new instead of the whole string where the precise match is

Comment: @GlennBoserupMøller it has more to do with your regex than anything - your words are split with "\W" so you should work around that - you can use a different regex, delimit using some other characters instead of a space, etc. Just a few ideas.